# Can Mac OS X Leopard & hence iPhone SDK be installed on the any of the new Intel i3/i5/i7 processors?

Tags: iphone

I know that it can be installed on Core 2 Duo & Dual core processors.
I am using it right now.But,I am planning to buy new machine & wanna make sure that if I buy i3/i5,should be able to install Mac OS X & able to do iPhone development.
Thanks.

Comment: Well... Hackintosh boards might be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing iPhone development on one of the new MacBook Pros (15'', core i5). Snow Leopard and XCode/iPhone SDK are working perfectly.

Not only: thanks to the 4 virtual cores of the new core i5, compiling apps is much, much faster. And Grand Central Dispatch of Snow Leopard does really help with that.

Comment: @user192024:
Thanks a lot.It's helpful. 
Well,I am not buying Mac.But I think from what you just mentioned,it's safe to assume that I can have one of i3/i5 & install Snow Leopard over it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Mac, of course it will work.  If not then the processor will work but you have to figure out the other things on your own.

Comment: I wont buy Mac.Planning to buy just CPU with one of the Intel processors.I will have Windows+Mac+Linux installed over it.
Currently, I am using same O/S combination on Dual Core with Mac OS X 10.5.6.
Thanks.

Comment: You are in the hackentosh world then and I cannot say much for sure.  I am 99% sure that the CPU will work fine, it will be the components you will have to worry about.